# Regular expression to extract integers

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I need help in extracting number from a column that store texts. In the text, there can be also some prices that I don't want to extract. As an example, if I have the following text:

```
text = "I have the following products 4526 and 4. The first one I paid $40 while the second one 30€. 
Here the link for the discount of 3.99: https://www.xysyffd.coom/7574@5757"
```

My expected result would be

```
[4526, 4]
```

Right now what I have used the following regular expression

```
'(?<![\d.])[0-9]+(?![\d.])'
```

which is able to discard the 3.99 but still it recognize the prices and the number in the link.
Any suggestion on how to update the re?

Comment: Like this? `(?<!\S)\d+\b(?!€|\.\d)` https://regex101.com/r/QI1mxq/1

Comment: Or `(?<!\S)\d+(?!\.\d)(?=[\s.!?,;])`

Comment: @trincot That is also nice, you could add the end of the string as well `(?<!\S)\d+(?!\.\d)(?=[\s.!?,;]|$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
(?<!\S)[0-9]+(?!\.\d|[^\s!?.])
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/kRVmGH/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\s!?.]                 any character except: whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " "), '!', '?', '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

[**Python code**](https://tio.run/##NY/BToQwFEX3fMWDuICohQg4YaLBpbPW3XQ0hJZpY2mb9o0MiSu/x6/yRxBmxs1Lbu7JfTl2RGF0Pk2yt8YhOB44vudHeAQXxfVDSF@SbXZb7a7jOqSEsq/tG/VhTXZJFCD3@O7RzXC0AdF8ckDBoTNKmUHqPVhn2KFFD0V5dw@NZlAQeF0Q6TyC0Rw2YBvJ4KrIYBBSnRc8b80ML32e/X7/EKD6mbtzqaT@mH@4U2DSt@ag560OclJVaxCI1q/TdBgGchz92HWMtMb06apcFU/lfKOgb7AV3C@SnHRSs0ap@OR9A/9SSWCd1Bhf2GSa/gA):

```py
import re
regex = r"(?<!\S)[0-9]+(?!\.\d|[^\s!?.])"
test_str = "I have the following products 4526 and 4. The first one I paid $40 while the second one 30€. \nHere the link for the discount of 3.99: https://www.xysyffd.coom/7574@5757"
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str)
print(matches)
```

**Results**: `['4526', '4']`

Comment: What if I have a number at the beginning of the sentence?

Comment: @Ibrahim [No problem](https://regex101.com/r/kRVmGH/3), it matches.

Comment: Yeah, my bad in some other part of the code! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can assert a whitspace boundary to the left, and exclude matching a dot followed by a digit or the euro sign.

```
(?<!\S)\d+\b(?!€|\.\d)
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert not a non whitespace char to the left (A whitespace boundary)
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(?!€|\.\d)` Negative lookahead to assert what is directly to the right is not `€` or `.` followed by a digit.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QI1mxq/1/) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qHexyJ)

Example

```
import re
 
pattern = r"(?<!\S)\d+\b(?!€|\.\d)"
s = ("I have the following products 4526 and 4. The first one I paid $40 while the second one 30€. \n"
    "Here the link for the discount of 3.99: https://w...content-available-to-author-only...d.coom/7574@5757\n")
 
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['4526', '4']
```